# Is youtube Api provide a method like setZOrderonTop()?

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am trying to add youtube player into GLSurfaceView but I am getting Transparent screen instead of video screen. I am getting audio proparly but not video. I know GLSurfaceView overlay on youtube player view but, how to resolve this problem?.